# How to check Android Log in Window's Terminal?

Tags: android, windows, terminal

I am working in an Android Project. I want to see Logs in Window terminal rather than in Android's Logcat.Any suggestion?. I put Logger in my project for example:

```
 Log.d("ufo","Plane inventory Listener is called");
```

I also want to see Logs of "ufo" in window's terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***You need to read [logcat documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html) for details.***

---

You can see log messages into terminal using below command

1. To see all logs

   adb logcat
2. Filter logs (like you want to see logs for *ufo*)

   adb logcat | grep "ufo"